# IIS with multiple roots

Tags: iis

Can IIS7 be setup to have many roots? Say I have a local server on our LAN called `jupiter`. Staff can view their sites via a folder structure such as `http://jupiter/staff/karen`. While this works ok, what they cannot do is use relative addressing to its full. Should they wish to link to a home page then using `href="/default.html"` or something similar will take then to the root of `jupiter` and not to their own top directory.

What is the easiest way to accomplish this? I know I can use ports (i.e. `http://jupiter:1001`) to get to karens site, but I would much prefer something like `http://karen.jupiter` or `http://jupiter/~karen`) where accessing the root will take them to the top of their own site structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get this to work you would need to:

- Configure your internal DNS to have many host names associated with this server.   You could probably use a wildcard DNS rule to achieve this easily.

  - jupiter
  - karen.jupiter
  - bob.jupiter
  - etc.
- Set up a virtual host for each user in the IIS configuration.  [Here is a guide](https://confluence.cornell.edu/display/CUWAL/Configuring+VirtualHost+in+IIS) that tells you how to do that.